# Restrict the output of posts from a specific date (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a regular dataframe with a time series. How can I infer date fields from a specific value? I tried to apply `pd.to_datetime` ,but some dates start to display month and day incorrectly (swap them). That is, the following occurs: `07-02-2022` to `2022-07-02`, but it should be `2020-02-07`.

Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
      date          infected_in_day
0     07-02-2022    15442.0
1     06-02-2022    18856.0
2     05-02-2022    22444.0
...
214   02-07-2021    6893.0
229   16-06-2021    5782.0
235   11-12-2020    40.0
236   09-12-2020    42.0
237   08-12-2020    41.0
```

I need to filter data by date `16-06-2021`, that is, do not display everything that was before. Like this:

```
      date          infected_in_day
0     07-02-2022    15442.0
1     06-02-2022    18856.0
2     05-02-2022    22444.0
...
214   02-07-2021    6893.0
229   16-06-2021    5782.0
```

Is there any way to do this without using `pd.to_datetime`? Or how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you have a problem with the datecolumn. If my assumtion is right, I would try to parse the data as I would expect to work with it something like this :

```
mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S")
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep='\t', parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=mydateparser)
```